# C# generics & not going insane

Tags: c#, java, generics

```
public <T extends java.util.EventListener> T[] getListeners(final Class<T> listenerClass) {
    ...
}
```

What is the equivalent c# generics notation of the above java generics?

Parameter listenerClass will be a type & not a object. But the object T has to belong to a specific hierachy.

Comment: so in java: i pass MyListener.class ..where MyListener is class name.. method wont allow objects as params

Comment: Is that just to be able to find out what `T` is? If so, that's not needed in C# because `T` is available inside the method.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
public T[] GetListeners<T>() where T : EventListener
{
}
```

Comment: what happened to the param?? i pass class (type) method return array of object of that type

Comment: Let's say the return type is an array of the type MyListener. You would call the method like this: MyListener[] mylisteners = GetListeners<MyListener>();

Comment: @pulancheck1988: Unlike in Java, in C# the generic argument is reified and accessible.  So while `T.class` is illegal in Java, the C# equivalent `typeof(T)` is perfectly legitimate and will return you a `Type` object corresponding to the type of `T`.  The Java idiom of passing around `Class<T>` objects is just a workaround for a limitation of Java's generics implementation; since C# does not have the same limitation, the idioms are different.